# can multiple instances of gazebo and/or roscore run in parallel

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, roscore, parallel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a project I am working on that would be incredibly helpful if I could run multiple instances of gazebo or multiple **roscore** simultaneously. Multiple gazebos would be ideal but if I could run more than 1 **roscore** that would work and just pass messages between the cores. Does anyone know if this can be done somehow? I haven't seen any documentation on being able to or not being able to run these simultaneously.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11395/can-multiple-instances-of-gazebo-and/or-roscore-run-in-parallel/) by [seth_g](https://answers.ros.org/users/1153/seth_g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2011-10-03

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2013-01-22**:
use  in the launch file to have different instances run in parallel on the same roscore

**Comment by [RainMan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33994/rainman/) on 2018-03-05**:
I tried group namespace thing, but it didn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.04 for ROS Kinetic distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roscore defaults to use port 11311.  If you use the environment variable ROS_MASTER_URI (documented [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_MASTER_URI) ) to change that port the 2nd master won't conflict.

You can also run multiple gazebo instances inside ROS if you launch them in different namespaces.  However there may be an issue if you try to run them on the same machine and the instances have to share a GPU.  Running them on 2 seperate machines will definitely avoid that.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-09**:
@tfoote : On a lighter vein, why was this port was chosen as the default port ? 11311 ? :-)

**Comment by [seth_g](https://answers.ros.org/users/1153/seth_g/) on 2011-10-04**:
Can you expand on the different namespaces idea? I've tried giving a different group namespace for each gazebo instance as well as trying to remap the node name with no success. Is the gazebo/gazebo (says this next to my node name) namespace what needs to change?